# How can I type Indian Rupee symbol?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, fonts

I want Indian Rupee Symbol (₹) font in my android, so I can type it in message or anywhere I would like to. But, I can't find it in my keyboard.

Can anybody please suggest me where can I get it?

I am using Samsung Galaxy Grand and Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Comment: You should change the title. Having the font and being able to type the character are two different things. AFAIK, all fonts on Android are unicode, and they should all have this symbol.

Comment: What keyboard to you use?

Comment: I stumbled on [this](http://androidtweak.in/rom/cyanogenmod/now-you-can-type-indian-rupee-symbol-using-cm10-stock-keyboard/) website after trying to answer your question which says CM10's stock keyboard has this symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recently released [`Google Hindi` IME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi) (Input Method Editor, a techy name for keyboard) which I now saw with my friend's Nexus 4. It has the requested Rupee symbol:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can try [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey). It shows the rupee symbol over the key 'X'.

[image: SwiftKey rupee symbol]

Just make sure you set the language of your phone to "English (India)" otherwise you won't get the rupee symbol ([link](http://support.swiftkey.net/knowledgebase/articles/30883-my-currency-key-on-the-home-keyboard-does-not-matc)).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard), which supports the ₹ symbol now. Just long-tap the $ key.

Answer (score -1):

If you hv swift key no need to pay money just click hold alphabet 'x'  you will get the option for ₹.  Thanks

Comment: Would you explain the reason behind posting this answer when the content is already covered [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/55651/96277), except the fact that the app is free to use now?